# Extract hash values (CRC) and path names from an archive

Tags: 7-zip, archiving, rar, crc, file-archiver

I have successfully extracted data from a large .rar archive (1.9TB) using 7-zip and now I want to delete the archive. However, before I do so, **I would like to save** path names and, most importantly, the corresponding **CRC values that are listed in the CRC column in the 7-zip file manager**.

The only way to do this that I know of is via cmd.exe with the following command `7z l -slt <archive.zip>`. However, this method is not very efficient for my purposes. For one thing, command prompt's output window is limited in size. I know that I can adjust buffer size (perhaps even up to 32766), but the archive has over a million files... What is even more problematic, though, is the fact that the output of this method has a format that, as far as I know, cannot be altered and it is as follows:

```
Path = -
Folder = -
Size = -
Packed Size = -
Modified = -
Created =
Accessed =
Attributes = -
Encrypted = -
Solid = -
Commented = -
Split Before = -
Split After = -
CRC = -
Host OS = -
Method = -
Version = -
Volume Index = -
```

Whereas what I'm looking for is an output per file that looks like this:

```
<CRC> <pathname>
```

For example:

```
60CD248A *Folder1\text1.txt
61CD248A *Folder1\Folder2\text1.txt
62CD248A *Folder1\Folder2\text2.txt
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Try redirecting the output into a file. Then you can write a script to parse the file ...

Comment: @DavidPostill This was very helpful. Using `7z l -slt <archive.zip> > <output.txt>` seems to bypass the cmd.exe buffer size limitation and the output file can be worked on. I will try to format it with Notepad++, because I'm not sure how to go about this with a script. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one line command code to get only CRC lines from command line output:

```bat
7z l -slt archive.zip >> "%tmp%\output.txt" && type "%tmp%\output.txt"|findstr /b CRC | clip && del /q /f "%tmp%\output.txt"
```

This command will put in your clipboard (Crtl+C) all lines contents `CRC - .....` from 7z command output.

To save in a file:

```bat
7z l -slt archive.zip >> "%tmp%\output.txt" && type "%tmp%\output.txt"|findstr /b CRC >>"c:\my_folder\my_save_output.txt" && del /q /f "%tmp%\output.txt"
```

To loop (via "for") and save CRC strings:

```bat
for /f tokens^=2*^delims^=^ ^-^  %i in ('7z l -slt archive.zip^|findstr /b CRC')do @echo/%i>>"c:\my_folder\my_save_output.txt"
```

- My 7Z version output looks like *CRC = STRINGS*, in my case, the delimiter changes to:

```bat
for /f tokens^=^2*^delims^=^=^  %i in ('7za l -slt archive.zip ^| find /i "crc"')do @echo/%i>>"c:\my_folder\my_save_output.txt"
```

**Obs.: 1)** There are 2 spaces in between **`^=^=`**   and   **`%i`**:

```bat
delims^=^= ←→ %i  --->  delims^=^=^  %i
```

**Obs.: 2)** The same apply to Path, just replace *CRC* to *Path*.

**Obs.: 3)** The executable file in portable version used is 7za.exe, may your have another name.

Comment: @ItWasntMe I'm not sure if I can afford all the beer that I owe you for solving all my IT problems. I tested (1) `7z l -slt archive.zip >>"%tmp%\output.txt && type "%tmp%\output.txt"|findstr /b CRC >>"c:\my_folder\my_save_output.txt" && del /q /f "%tmp%\output.txt"`(works great; only missing a `"` after the first `output.txt`); (2) `for /f tokens^=^2*^delims^=^=^  %i in ('7za l -slt archive.zip ^| find /i "crc"')do @echo/%i>>"c:\my_folder\my_save_output.txt"` (works great).

Comment: @ItWasntMe Is it possible to extract `<CRC> <Path>` at the same time? I could copy both output .txt into Excel and then use CONCATENATE to combine them but Excel has a row limit that will be exceeded with large files...

Comment: @ItWasntMe That's great. Thanks. I use [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) to check file integrity. It creates .sfv files with input in this format `<relative path> <CRC>` ([example](https://ibb.co/cgnv368)). CRC are aligned to the right, but it's not important.