# Can I get the real CRC of RAR-compressed files?

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, hashing

In RAR5 archives, the CRCs of files seem to be hashed again with the modification time of the corresponding files (so the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1519299/extract-hash-values-crc-and-path-names-from-an-archive) doesn't work).

I **EITHER** need the real CRCs from the archive, which 7z can indeed show via:

`7z t <archive> -scrc <filename>`.

But the problem here is that you *have* to supply the filename. Is there also a way to directly print a list of **all** files in the RAR-archive and their CRCs?

**OR** I need a method to check if a file is valid according to the RAR-CRC (which remember, is the standard CRC mysteriously hashed again). I suppose that would work like:

"Hash file and get CRC" ➔ "Hash CRC with mtime of archive to get RAR-CRC" ➔ "Compare"

But I don't know how to do the second step!

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1519299/extract-hash-values-crc-and-path-names-from-an-archive) help ?

Comment: @harrymc the problem here is that only works for the normal RAR3 archives which have plain CRCs. The new RAR5 ones hash the CRC again with the mtime (I assume). I mean, I could work through the Unrar source code (the decompressor is open source), but that's likely over my head ...

Comment: I'm not sure about this : see in "RAR 5.0 archive format" section [File hash record](https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm#hashrecord).